# How to make a WhatsApp like `RecyclerView`?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[image]This may be possible of duplicate question i have tried all things none of it works i need to make whatsapp like chat model using `RecyclerView` and at the bottom `EditText` and a `Button` bottom my problem is i can have `EditText` and bottom at the bottom but i need scroll to view that `EditText` and `Button`, what i should have  when user enter that page `EditText` and `Buttonb should appear without scrolling and one more problem there is lots of space between two items in that`RecyclerView` how to reduce that space let me post what i did so far:

My Recyclerview ChatLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/constraint_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Enter Message"
            android:lines="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How to do this as am new for android development someone please help me!

Comment: Add a *screenshot* to your question for better visualization.

Comment: @CodeWalker please take a look

Comment: your question is hard to understand. really!!!

Comment: Please post your chat row item code because of that from above posted code there is difficult to understand whats going on ? kindly post complete code. Might be with your row item code. @M.Yougeshwaran

Answer (score 0):

You should change the android:height in layout that u use in your RecyclerViewAdapter to wrap_content

And also in your manifest

```
<activity
        ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        ...
></activity>
```

Comment: am just using this in tab fragment

Comment: yes, that also work, just add that configuration to your activity that load your tab fragment. It will rearrange the height of the layout automatically based on soft keyboard show up

Answer (score 0):

Their are many libraries out there.[This](https://github.com/DeromirNeves/whatsapp-android) library is a sample Android App which can be used as a starter application for a chat application.You can take reference or implemented this library in your project

Answer (score 0):

check your row item(layout xml file) which is used in your viewholder. I think you have used match_parent in your parent view. Make it as **wrap_content**.

For that scrolling issue, check your code for smoothScrollToPosition(int). may be you have used this method in your code.

Comment: can you explain that scrolling issue again? is that the recyclerview scrolling to bottom?

Comment: can you post some sample of that method so i havent tried yet

Comment: i think i didn't get that problem. can you explain more??

Comment: in the layout which i have posted i need to scroll to view that editext and button but i want to make it fix at the bottom like we have in whats app

Comment: android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_linear_layout_Id" , put this inside recyclerview tag. and dont forget to add an id to the bottom linear layout (here i used bottom_linear_layout_Id) ** if you want you can make that recyclerview height as match_parent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123328/discussion-between-m-yogeshwaran-and-chathura).